# Python: Syntax error in list comprehension statement

Tags: python

```
missing_buckets = [x in timebuckets if ((x not in found_tenors) and (x == '1y' or x[-1] != 'y'))]
```

I get the error:

```
missing_buckets = [x in timebuckets if ((x not in found_tenors) and (x == '1y' or x[-1] != 'y'))]
                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: A carat is not an error.

Comment: I think you copy pasted the python statement twice as opposed to the error.

Comment: Please provide a bit more explicit title, like "Python: problem with list comprehensions" or something like that.

Comment: I'll update the question with the error msg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
missing_buckets = [x for x in timebuckets if ((x not in found_tenors) and (x == '1y' or  x[-1] != 'y'))]
                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: I knew it would be something silly like that. Thanks!. I have been swapping between too many languages lately.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot "for x in ":

`missing_buckets = [x for x in timebuckets if ((x not in found_tenors) and (x == '1y' or x[-1] != 'y'))]`